# Breeze: how to make the original values map more secure

Tags: breeze

I would like to use the OriginalValuesMap to do some custom auditing on save. In the breeze docs, they mention that you may need to add additional security (it's coming from the client, so don't trust it).

My goal is to find a way to validate that the original values map is not tampered with, so that my audit entries are accurate. (An example of an exploit that I want to defeat would be of someone altering a value in the original values map to make it look as if they had not changed a value).

I was thinking about doing something like this:

1. When the data is queried from the server, apply a hash to the values of the entity
2. Include the hash in the serialization graph of the entity (so the hash is an opaque value sent to the client, but the salt for the hash is a secret known only to the server).
3. When the client calls save changes, echo the hash back to the server
4. Inside of beforesaveentities, reconstruct the original entity using values from the OriginalValuesMap.
5. A hash of this "de-deltaed" entity should match the original.

My only problem is, I don't know how to insert the hash into breeze's serialization graph and extract it back out.

It looks like there are several promising extension points (custom serializer on the client, custom content provider).

How would one do this?
Is there a better way?
Am I nuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nuts.

But seriously, the most straightforward way is to re-query the existing data from the database 
to see that the `originalValuesMap` matches what is in the db.  If they don't, either the 
`originalValuesMap` has been tampered with, or the db record has been updated (by someone else) 
since it was queried.  The save should be aborted in either case.

While you are at it, you'll probably want to enforce some other rules on the server:

- Some entities are illegal to save (e.g. users are not allowed to add new Countries to the lookup table)
- Some entities can only be saved by users in a certain role (e.g. administrators)
- Some entities can only be saved by users that 'own' them (e.g. a user can only update an order that belongs to them)
- The values are sanity-checked (e.g. prices are positive, quantities are reasonable)
- The operation is sanity-checked (e.g no user can create more than 1000 orders in one hour)
- Other business rules are applied (e.g. credit limits, time-of-day restrictions, etc.)

Obviously some of these won't apply to your app, but you may find that there are some rules
that require querying the database anyway.  So that's how you should verify your `originalValuesMap`.

If you are intent on using your "hash" technique, the easiest way to get the data back and forth to the client is to add a property for it in your domain model base class that isn't mapped to the database.  You'll populate the property on the server before serialization.